# One PC Grappling multiple creatures

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, forced-movement

In my D&D 5e campaign I'm playing a Barbarian that I've focused on grappling and pulling enemies around the battlefield.

Can I grapple multiple enemies at once, one in each hand for example? If I can, can I force drag both at the same time? Is it still half speed or a quarter if I can do that?

I've found multiple sources contradicting whether it does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can grapple one target per free hand

The section for grappling in the *Player's Handbook* reads:

> The target of your grapple must be no more than one size larger than you, and it must be within your reach. Using at least one free hand, you try to seize the target by making a grapple check, a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target chooses the ability to use). If you succeed, you subject the target to the grappled condition...
>
>  - *PHB 195*

As long as you have a free hand, and the target meets the criteria, you are able to attempt a grapple.

## You can drag both, at a quarter speed

The section goes on to say:

> When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

A grappled creature can be moved with you, but it halves your movement speed. Moving the second creature halves your movement speed again to one quarter speed.